# How to track what triggered my pipeline on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using YML file to configure my azure pipelines. My pipeline can either be triggered by new commits to development branch and/or scheduled cron. How can I track which triggered the pipeline? I wanted to do some task based on what triggered by pipeline, whether from a new commit or a cron. It's a small add-on task, so I am avoiding writing a new pipeline to separate the tasks. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code sample:

```
trigger:
  - development

schedules:
  - cron: '0 0 * * *' # will run midnight every day
    displayName: 'Midnight tests' (UTC - 7:00)'
    branches:
          include:
            - development
        always: true

stages:
### do some work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could add task bash and enter script `printenv` to print all pipeline env variable. Then we could see the variable `BUILD_REASON`, we can track this variable to check how the build pipeline is triggered.

Schedule is trigger from cron, IndividualCI is trigger from commit push. You could check the pic below.

[image]

Comment: I did :) Thanks again for your help